# Source class "\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql" for "Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\MysqlFactory" generation does not exist

Tags: linux, magento2

i'm trying to install  **Magento 2** in localhost, and get an error when i want to connect the database.

The error is:

*Source class "\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql" for "Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\MysqlFactory" generation does not exist.*

[image]

OS: **linux mint 19.1 x64.**

DB: **MySQL.**

I create a database (*magento*) and a user (*magento*), asigning all privileges.

When run:

```
mysql -u magento -p
```

And then put his password can access, so all is fine here.

The path dir is: */var/www/html/magento2*

i'm follow this tutorial: https://tecadmin.net/install-magento-on-ubuntu-16-04/

what should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Change the Full Release **with Sample Data** of Magento for the Full Release **with NO Sample Data**, and solved.

[image]